# Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for NzModalRef: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, ng-zorro-antd

I'm doing an angular project using the NZ-Zorro library and I'm having a hard time finding what are these parameters that aren't being solved from NzModalRef, when I try to run the test --code-coverage to do the tests. I get this error.

Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for NzModalRef: (?, ?, ?).

That's my .spec

```
import { NzNotificationService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/notification';
import { MinistryService } from './../../ministry.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  NzModalModule,
  NzModalService,
  NzModalRef,
} from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { MembersService } from '../../members.service';
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import {
  UntypedFormBuilder,
  UntypedFormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormNewMemberComponent } from './form-new-member.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('FormNewMemberComponent', () => {
  let component: FormNewMemberComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormNewMemberComponent>;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let fb: UntypedFormBuilder;
  let validateForm: UntypedFormGroup;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FormNewMemberComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NzModalModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        MembersService,
        NzModalService,
        HttpClient,
        Validators,
        NzModalRef,
        MinistryService,
        NzNotificationService,
        UntypedFormBuilder,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fb = TestBed.inject(UntypedFormBuilder);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormNewMemberComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My .ts

```
import { NzModalRef } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { Ministry } from './../../ministry/ministry.model';
import { MemberPageComponent } from './../member-page.component';
import { MembersService } from '../../members.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  UntypedFormBuilder,
  UntypedFormControl,
  UntypedFormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { NzNotificationService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/notification';
import { MinistryService } from '../../ministry.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-new-member',
  templateUrl: './form-new-member.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-new-member.component.scss'],
})
export class FormNewMemberComponent implements OnInit {
  validateForm!: UntypedFormGroup;
  isVisible = false;
  pagina!: MemberPageComponent;
  members: any;
  ministrys: Ministry[] = []
  listOfMinistrys!: Ministry[]

  createNotificationSuccess(type: string): void {
     this.notification.create(
      type,
      'Sucesso!',
      'Membro adicionado.',
      {nzDuration: 2000}
      );
  }

  createNotificationError(type: string): void {
    this.notification.create(
     type,
     'Erro!',
     'Membro não foi adicionado.',
     {nzDuration: 2000}
     );
 }

  constructor(
    private fb: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private membersService: MembersService,
    private nzModalRef: NzModalRef,
    private notification: NzNotificationService,
    private ministryService: MinistryService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required]],
      checkPassword: [null, [Validators.required, this.confirmationValidator]],
      name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      phoneNumber: [null, [Validators.required]],
      cpf: [null, [Validators.required]],
      rg: [null, [Validators.required]],
      ministry: [null, [Validators.required]],
      address: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.showMinistry()
  }
  submitForm(): void {
    if (this.validateForm.valid) {
      this.membersService.create(this.validateForm.value).subscribe(
        (success) => {
          this.createNotificationSuccess('success')
          this.destroyModal();
        },
        (error) => {
          this.createNotificationError('error')
        }
      );
    } else {
      Object.values(this.validateForm.controls).forEach((control) => {
        if (control.invalid) {
          control.markAsDirty();
          control.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  updateConfirmValidator(): void {
    Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      this.validateForm.controls['checkPassword'].updateValueAndValidity()
    );
  }

  confirmationValidator = (
    control: UntypedFormControl
  ): { [s: string]: boolean } => {
    if (!control.value) {
      return { required: true };
    } else if (control.value !== this.validateForm.controls['password'].value) {
      return { confirm: true, error: true };
    }
    return {};
  };

  destroyModal(): void {
    this.nzModalRef.destroy({ newMember: this.validateForm.value });
  }

  showMinistry(){
    this.ministryService.getMinistrys().subscribe((data) => {
      this.ministrys = data;

      this.listOfMinistrys = [...this.ministrys];
    });
  }
}
```

My service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Member } from './member-page/members.model';
import { Observable, take} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


const apiMembers = 'http://localhost:3000/membrosBd';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MembersService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMembers(): Observable<Member[]> {
    return this.http.get<Member[]>(apiMembers)
  }

  create(member: Member): Observable<Member>{
    return this.http.post<Member>(apiMembers, member).pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```

And my module

```
import { NzNotificationModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/notification';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { NzPaginationModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/pagination';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MemberPageComponent } from './member-page/member-page.component';
import { NzTableModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/table';
import { NzAutocompleteModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/auto-complete';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { NzInputModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/input';
import { NzIconModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/icon';
import { NzDropDownModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/dropdown';
import { NzModalModule, NzModalRef } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { FormNewMemberComponent } from './member-page/form-new-member/form-new-member.component';
import { NzFormModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/form';
import { NzSelectModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';
import { MinistryComponent } from './ministry/ministry.component';
import { NzListModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/list';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MemberPageComponent,
    FormNewMemberComponent,
    MinistryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NzTableModule,
    NzPaginationModule,
    NzAutocompleteModule,
    NzButtonModule,
    NzInputModule,
    NzIconModule,
    NzDropDownModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NzModalModule,
    NzFormModule,
    NzSelectModule,
    NzNotificationModule,
    NzListModule,
  ],
  providers: [NzModalRef],
  exports: [
    MemberPageComponent
  ]
})
export class MembrosModule { }
```

I thank anyone who can help me.

hope that the nzmodalref parameters can be solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same message.
Because "NzModalRef" is not a provider, it helped me to remove the definition "NzModalRef" from the list of "providers: [ ... ]".

My problem was on version ng-zorro 17.0.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).